# How to have search & sort in sqlite database row value by substring from its left start in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to search & sort a sqlite database row value with a substring in it.For example United unit is the fetched value means I would like to seek the on entering value in edittext in order of entering u,n,i,t in edittext it should fetch it from United only not second word.Kindly provide a snippet to achieve this.Thanks a lot.

Comment: could you elaborate a but more...

Comment: I needs to start retrieving from first character postion sqlite database row value,for this whats the query I need to use

Comment: see like  query for more info

Comment: I used like "%"searchString"%" in the query but I am getting the string matched with anypart of the row value and returning it..

Comment: Do you know what [the `%` means for `LIKE`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like)?